# How can I change the customError configuration set by the web.config during runtime?

Tags: asp.net, web-config, custom-error-pages, custom-error-handling

I currently have a customError node in my web.config like the following:

```
<customErrors mode="On" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite" defaultRedirect="~/error.aspx">
    <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/themes/generic/common/error-notfound.aspx"/>
</customErrors>
```

During runtime, I want to be able to change the application behavior to act as if the attribute redirectMode was set to ResponseRedirect instead of ResponseRewrite. I must be able to do this without making a change to the web.config file. Is this possible, and if so how? Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer. 
Inside an IHttpModule, attach an event handler for the Error HttpApplicationEvent. This event handler should only trigger when the customErrors section of the web.config is set to ResponseRewrite. The event handler executes before the customError configuration.

```
public class ErrorHandlingHttpModule : IHttpModule
{
    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        // Read web.config
        var configuration = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");
        var systemWebSection = configuration.GetSectionGroup("system.web") as SystemWebSectionGroup;

        if (systemWebSection == null || 
            systemWebSection.CustomErrors == null || 
            systemWebSection.CustomErrors.Mode == CustomErrorsMode.Off ||
            systemWebSection.CustomErrors.RedirectMode != CustomErrorsRedirectMode.ResponseRewrite)
        {
            return;
        }

        var customErrorsSection = systemWebSection.CustomErrors;
        context.Error +=
            (sender, e) =>
            {
                if (customErrorsSection.Mode == CustomErrorsMode.RemoteOnly && context.Request.IsLocal)
                {
                    return;
                }

                var app = (HttpApplication)sender;
                var httpException = app.Context.Error as HttpException;

                // Redirect to a specific url for a matching status code
                if (httpException != null)
                {
                    var error = customErrorsSection.Errors.Get(httpException.GetHttpCode().ToString("D"));
                    if (error != null)
                    {
                        context.Response.Redirect(error.Redirect);
                        return;
                    }
                }

                // Redirect to the default redirect
                context.Response.Redirect(customErrorsSection.DefaultRedirect);
            };
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
    }
}
```